# Getting field values of HTML input boxes that were "echoed" inside PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a login/activation page (as part of requirements for an assignment), where if the activation went successful, the person sees the login page. I have the HTML code for the login page inside my PHP block (because I don't know the safest and most secure way to hide a form), and was wondering how to get the information that the user enters into the username,password fields.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* Project information:
 * Author: Michael Warren
 * FileName: login.php
 * Creation Date: 9/12/2014
 */
// create variables for userName (or email address), password, needsActivation, activationCode
$userName = "";
$password = "";
$needsActivation = ((isset($_POST["activate"])) ? (bool)($_POST["activate"]) : false);
$activationCode = "";

// variable to check if the current user of this page has been activated
$userActivated = !($needsActivation);

// JavaScript messages that tell the user the status of their activation
$activationSuccess = '<script>alert("Activation successful! Bringing up the log in page.");</script>';
$activationFailed = '<script>alert("Activation failed. You have been sent another activation e-mail.");</script>';

// JavaScript messages that tell the user about the login
$missingUserName = '<script>alert("Username required.");</script>';
$missingPassword = '<script>alert("Password required");</script>';
$invalidUserName = '<script>alert("Invalid username entered.");</script>';
$invalidPassword = '<script>alert("Invalid password entered.");</script>';
$successfulLogin = '<script>alert("You have successfully logged in!");</script>';

if ($needsActivation)
{   
    // get the information from the query string (or the POSTed data)
    $userName = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $activationCode = $_POST["activationCode"];
    // check the activationCode
    // if the activationCode checks out (in this project, that just means that the length of the activation code is 50 characters)
    if (strlen($activationCode) == 50)
    {
        // user has been activated
        $userActivated = true;
        // send email and/or JavaScript message telling them that
        echo $activationSuccess;
        mail($userName, 
            "Activation Successful",
            <<<HERE
Your activation was a success. You can now use this site. Your login credentials are as follows:

UserName: $userName
Password: $password
HERE
);
        }
        // otherwise
        else
        {
            // deny access to login page
            // send email to the user to try again, and inform them that it has been done
            echo $activationFailed;
        }
    }
    if ($userActivated)
    {
        // show the login page
        echo <<<HERE
        <div id="contents">
            <div id="clearfix">
                <div id="main">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p>Log in to the site using your e-mail as your password.</p>
                    <form class="message">
                        <label>
                            <p class="descriptor">User name: </p><input type="text" name="userNameField" value=""></input>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <p class="descriptor">Password: </p><input type="password" name="passwordField" value=""></input>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" name="LogInButton" value="Log in"></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
HERE;
    }

    function checkLogin()
    {

    }
?>
    <body>
</html>
```

I was going to try having the button trigger checkLogin(), but the first step is to know how to retrieve that user input. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: My other idea was one that I previously used: have the button POST data to the page, and then check it `if (isset($_POST['LogInButton']))`, but my worry is the exact same

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. If the user hasn't logged in yet, you don't have the username and password, so how can you fill in the fields automatically? They're not sent until after the user submits the login form, not when the form is being displayed.

Comment: When they hit that button, I suppose you can get the fields by name. This is what I was questioning.

Comment: Hit what button, the submit button? That will send the form, and then the script will run again. This time, `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` will contain what the user entered into the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you plan to post the form back to PHP set an action attribute on the form and let it be posted by the submit button, on server side you can access these values from $_POST array.

IF you want to capture these values on client side, use jQuery or plain JavaScript, possible assign some ids to the inputs for that you can easily target them.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. Would the $_POST array contain the values from the input fields, as if the HTML were declared outside the PHP block? That is, can I use one of my ideas and capture the input from the fields by name, as usual?

Comment: The browser will never know where they were declared as long as they are, so will behave normally like an ordinary form.

Comment: Is this because of the fact that, to the PHP code, all of the HTML/CSS/JavaScript is just string(s)?

Comment: @MikeWarren That is correct. They are just strings. The interpretation of these strings handled client side is taken care of by the browser.

Comment: Just have a look at the source after the page is rendered, you will see nothing but plain html/css/js